# CSP error with Rails 6, React and Webpack dev server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I'm building an API using rails and sending that data to my React Views. Unfortunately, whenever I run the webpack-dev-server from the CLI and go to localhost:3035, I get this error

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at data:font/woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAJd6AB… ("default-src").
```

If I load localhost on port 3000 though, everything works fine.

Anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my understanding of how Rails, React and webpack work. Turns out that Webpack is serving up files from port:3035 and rails from port:3030. When I have both servers running(i.e rails and webpack) and make requests via the rails port:3030, the hot reload feature of webpack works and I get no CSP errors.